# Plugin 'maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1' not found

Tags: java, maven-3, serenity-bdd, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am getting `'maven-failsafe-plugin2.22.7' not found` while importing `https://github.com/serenity-bdd/screenplay-pattern-todomvc.git` and setting it up as Maven project in Intellij idea. Any idea what could be the issue?

Edit: the solution was to run the code using `mvn clean verify` command in the terminal. Using this i receive no error whatsoever.

Comment: Please don't share your code examples as screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Invalidate Caches. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: Tried few times did not work. Also tried deleting whole folder and re importing from github still same error

Comment: also try to find this "maven-failsafe-plugin" in mvnrepository and try to install it from there, mb it will help somehow, if not, try another version, not 2.22.1